# Pass ARRAY arguments to set-alias in modulefile

Tags: arrays, bash, alias, environment-modules, modulefile

all.
I need to use a function that must be declared within an environment module, so I'm trying to define it with set-alias.
Here's the tricky thing, the parameter it takes is an array.
So far, as a test I've tried this:

```
set-alias test  {
    declare -a argArray=(\"${@}\");
    echo \${\#argArray}
}
```

which returns zero : (

```
0
```

the (potentially) awful amount of back-slashes is needed, as module doesn't get along well with single quotes (so they say in manpage).
can somebody explain me what's going on?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use `set-alias` for writing functions
- *Environment modules* are **tcl** based

You can use `proc` for writing functions:

```
proc test {arg1} {
    return [llength $arg1]
}
```